# Function to generate barplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a piece of code that I need to run 40 times for each country in my data. I would like to instead write a function that would allow me enter the country name as an argument and thus perform the steps instead of replacing the country name 7 times in the same identical code for each of the 40 countries (actually shh, I have done this already). 
The reproducible code is as follows:

```
dict_usa={'NYC': 0.10,
         'LA': -0.05,
         'Chicago': -0.16,
         'Miami': -0.04,
         'Detroit': -0.19,
         'Seattle': -0.2,
         'Boston': -0.3}


df_usa=pd.DataFrame({'usa':dict_usa})
df_usa.columns=['grade']
df_usa['positive']=df_usa['grade']>0
##### Plot
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.35)
df_usa['grade'].plot(kind='barh', 
      color=df_usa.positive.map({True:'b',
                                 False:'r'}),
    title="usa")
pylab.savefig('C:\\filepath\\Visuals\\test\\usatest.png')
```

This produces the dataframe df_usa with a column of values for grade and generates a column called positive that is True if the value of grade is positive and False if negative.

```
df_usa.head.()
             grade  positive
Boston   -0.30     False
Chicago  -0.16     False
Detroit  -0.19     False
LA       -0.05     False
Miami    -0.04     False
```

Then a bar plot is generated whereby positive bars are blue and negatives are red as follows:
[image: Bar plot for US]

Now I want to do exactly this for 40 other countries for which I have city dictionaries in dict_country format. 
I tried the following:

```
def countryplot(df_country, country, dictname):
    df_country=pd.DataFrame({country: dictname})
    df_country.columns=['grade']
    df_country['positive']=df_country['grade']>0
    ##### Plot
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.35)
    df_country['disc'].plot(kind='barh', 
              color=df_country.positive.map({True:'b',
                                             False:'r'),
    title=country)    
    pylab.savefig('C:\\filepath\\Visuals\\'+country+'.png')
    return
```

When I use this function:

```
    countryplot(df_country='df_usa',country="'usa'",dictname='dict_usa')
```

I receive the following error:

```
    ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I'm a beginner - but very much devoted to learning Python for data analysis. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what `df_country.head()` shows ?

Comment: why do you have double quotes around usa? Also, you don't need to have the variables in that function call. You shouldn't have df_country as a variable you're passing to your function if you're creating it inside your function...

Comment: Spandan - I've added more information to answer your question. Thanks Mauve. Good call! I've taken it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have it here. Thanks for all the pointers. This works:

```
def countryplot(country,dictname):
    df_country=pd.DataFrame({country: dictname})
    df_country.columns=['grade']
    df_country['positive']=df_country['grade']>0
    ##### Plot
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.35)
    df_country['grade'].plot(kind='barh', 
              color=df_country.positive.map({True:'b',
                                             False:'r'}),
    title=country)    
    pylab.savefig('C:\\filepath\\Visuals\\test'+country+'.png')
return

countryplot(country="'usa'",dictname=dict_usa)
```